# Weird table view height

Tags: ios, objective-c

I want to get table view height, and use KVO for that. I use following:

```
    [self.selectionTableView addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"contentSize" options:NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew context:NULL];

}

- (void)observeValueForKeyPath:(NSString *)keyPath ofObject:(id)object change:(NSDictionary<NSString *,id> *)change context:(void *)context {
    if(object == self.selectionTableView && [keyPath isEqualToString:@"contentSize"]) {

        [self.backgroundView mas_updateConstraints:^(MASConstraintMaker *make) {
            make.top.equalTo(self.selectionTableView.mas_bottom);
            make.left.bottom.right.equalTo(self.view);
        }];

        NSLog(@"h? %f", self.selectionTableView.contentSize.height);

    }
}
```

I want to mention that i also have other table, called table view. But i want to get height of selection table view.

But when table is loaded i can see following in log:

```
2017-06-14 17:08:53.524 Engineering[27338:1452963] h? 1200.000000
2017-06-14 17:08:53.524 Engineering[27338:1452963] h? 1200.000000
2017-06-14 17:08:53.526 Engineering[27338:1452963] h? 1200.000000
2017-06-14 17:08:53.527 Engineering[27338:1452963] h? 1200.000000
2017-06-14 17:08:53.530 Engineering[27338:1452963] h? 834.000000
2017-06-14 17:08:53.535 Engineering[27338:1452963] h? 468.000000
2017-06-14 17:08:53.537 Engineering[27338:1452963] h? 102.000000
```

Correct height is 102, but i wonder where other numbers come from?

Comment: You are correct to get height using KVO, but if you using tableview cell having another tableview and your going to set inner tableview cell contain height as outer tableview cell height, you can not get exactly contain height. so Can you explain hierarchy of your design?

Comment: @Hitesh first table is on screen, second one (selection) is hidden (attached bottom side to top of view, so invisible). Later it show up from top on screen animated.